# What do backticked options mean?

Tags: shell, backticks

I [noticed](http://packetfactory.openwall.net/projects/libnet/dist/deprecated/manual/6.html) this command:

```
gcc -Wall `libnet-config --defines` libnet-example-x.c -o libnet-example-x `libnet-config --libs`
```

What is the meaning of `libnet-config --defines` and `libnet-config --libs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is executing a program that generates the necessary gcc arguments to compile an application that uses libnet.

Execute this at the command line and you will see what is going on:

```
 libnet-config --defines
```

Comment: I see , thank you. but it give me some undeclared errors when i make the example, for example:LN_ERR_WARNING. i think i miss something :(

Comment: as you say, "libnet-config --libs" generates '-lnet'

Comment: @sharp, If you are having compilation problems I suggest you open another question.  Getting something compile might have been your goal, but is outside the scope of the question you asked.

Answer (score 1):

`libnet-config` is an executable that will return a list of `-D...` options for gcc when called with the argument `--defines` and a list of `-l...` with the other argument.